# filter option in a grid

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

i use a filter option in a grid where i can select per column what i want to filter. For the options i need to do this:

```
Ext.ux.ajax.SimManager.init({
    delay: 300,
    defaultSimlet: null
}).register({
    'filterEvents': {
        data: [
            ['Dag 1', 'Dag 1'],
            ['Dag 2', 'Dag 2']
        ],
        stype: 'json'
    }
});

 dagenFilter = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     fields: ['id', 'text'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'filterEvents',
        reader: 'array'
    }
});
```

But because the filter options need to be dynamic and not static i want to load the options from a service. The output of that json looks like this

```
{
"dagen": [{
    "name": "Dag 1",
    "reference": "Dag 1"
}, {
    "name": "Dag 2",
    "reference": "Dag 2"
}, {
    "name": "Dag 3",
    "reference": "Dag 3"
}, {
    "name": "Dag 4",
    "reference": "Dag 4"
}]
```

}

but i am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "filter option in a grid" you are referring to [FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature) the answer is easy. A ListFilter can be backed by a DataStore.

Take a look at the `options` config of ListFilter [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter). Specifically, `store` and `phpMode` might also be relavant. Here is an example of one:

```
{
    header: 'List Filter Column',
    dataIndex: 'list_data',
    width: 120,
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        store: Ext.getStore('FilterOptions'),
        phpMode: true
    }
}
```